# What is current best practice around use of strings in cross-platform C and C++ APIs?

Tags: c++, c, api, cross-platform

I looks like I may need to embark on some cross-platform project and part of it will have to be done in C or C++ (not decided yet hence the question is about them both). I will be dealing mostly with the text-based stuff and strings in general.

That C/C++ will have an API callable from the higher-level platform-dependent code.

**My question is:** what type(s) is it advisable to use to work with strings, in particular when declaring public interfaces? Are there any recommended standard techniques? Are there things to avoid?

I have little experience of writing C or C++ code, and even that was on Windows, so nothing like cross-platform here at all. So what I'm really looking for is for something to get me on the right way and avoid doing stupid things which are bound to cause a lot of pain.

---

**Edit 1:** To give a bit more context about the intended use.
The API will be consumed by:

- Objective C on iPhone/iPad/Mac via NSString  and friends. The API can be statically linked, so no need to worry about .so .dll issues here.
- Java via JNI on Android and other Java platforms
- .NET via p/invoke from the managed C# code or natively statically linked if using C++/CLI.
- There are some thoughts about using *lua* somehow/somewhere in this context. Don't know if this has any bearing on anything though.

Comment: I would recommend writing the functionality you need in the style you are most comfortable with.  I personally think that seeing std::string in interfaces saves my life every day, but I can't say that for you.

After you solve that problem, solve the separate problem of writing adapters for each of your bindings.  They are separate problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rules

- Use UTF formats to store strings, *not* "code pages" or whatnot (<strike>UTF-16 is probably easier</strike> edit: I totally forgot about byte order issues; UTF-8 is probably the way to go).
- Use null-terminated strings instead of counted strings, as these are the easiest to access from most languages. But be careful about buffer overflows.
  **Update 6 years later:** I recommended this API for interoperability reasons (since so many already use null-termination, and there are multiple ways to represent counted strings), not the best one from a best-design standpoint. Today I would probably say the former is less important and recommend using counted strings rather than null-terminated strings if you can do it.
- Do not even *try* to use classes like `std::string` to pass around strings to/from the user. Even your *own* program can break after upgrading your compiler/libraries (since their implementation detail is just that: an implementation detail), let alone the fact that non-C++ programs will have trouble with it.
  **Update 6 years later:** This is *strictly for language and ABI compatibility reasons* with *other languages*, not general advice for C++ program development. If you're doing C++ development, cross-platform or otherwise, use the STL! i.e. only follow this advice if you need to call your code from other languages.
- Avoid allocating strings for the user unless it's truly painful for the user otherwise. Instead, take in a buffer and fill it up with data. That way you don't have to force the user to use a particular function to free the data. (This is also often a performance advantage as well, since it lets the user allocate small buffers on the stack. But if you *do* do that, **provide your own function** to free the data. You can't assume that your `malloc` or `new` can be freed with their `free` or `delete` -- they often can't be.)

#### Note:

Just to clarify, "let the user allocate the buffer" and "use NULL-terminated strings" do *not* run against each other. You still need to get the buffer length from the user, but you include the NULL when you terminate the string. My point was *not* that you should make a function similar to `scanf("%s")`, which is obviously unusably dangerous -- you still need the buffer length from the user. i.e. Do pretty much what Windows does in this regard.

Comment: Depending on what he's doing, UTF-8 might be the easiest.

Comment: @James: I was actually going to mention that, but I was afraid that someone reading this would likely incorrectly start using UTF-8 with the `___A` version of the Windows API functions (instead of properly converting them to UTF-16, which is a little annoying), so I said UTF-16 instead. But yeah, if you don't care too much about this potential accident, then UTF-8 is indeed probably the easiest.

Comment: You can also provide wrapper functions to use std::string, provided they're inline in the header files only and not part of the compiled library.

Comment: "Use null-terminated strings" is a bad advice, IMO. The whole point is contradictory once you mention buffer overflows. Mind you, I'm not saying that you can't (by convention) null-terminate your counted strings.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: The point here is interoperability, not safety. There's only one way to do null-termination, but there are multiple ways to do length counting (e.g. BSTR, an array structure with a pointer and a length, etc.).

Comment: It's better to have a struct/class which keeps track of the length. That's a whole lot faster when doing `write()`s and such.

Comment: @Mehrdad: could you elaborate a bit on UTF/UTF-8/UTF-16 please? Are we talking about encoding the inputs the API accepts and then working with them internally as UTF strings? Or are we talking merely about use of `wchar_t`? And what is this about UTF-8 being easier than UTF-16 and vice versa?

Comment: In some platforms wchar_t is 16-bit (Windows), elsewhere it's 32-bit (Linux, Mac OS X), so be careful with the memory layout. For file names Windows uses UTF-16, Linux and Mac use UTF-8, but it's easy to convert between the two. UTF-8 is easy, because there're typically no byte order problems. In UTF-16 you may have to describe the byte order. And wchar_t could theoretically be UTF-16 or UTF-32, MSB or LSB. That's why UTF-8 is easier in a protocol.

Comment: @Tamas For filenames, just keep it simple: ascii alnum, -, _, and pretty much nothing else.  That way you have a fighting chance of being portable.  For text, more generally, UTF-8 fits in a `char`; afterwords, it's up to you to do what has to be done. `wchar_t` is a can of worms when it comes to portability: avoid it.

Comment: @Tamas: Totally agree; I forgot about byte order. Updated my answer to reflect that, thanks! :)

Comment: @0xC0000022L: 6 years later I'm seeing this answer and realizing I agree with you. Not sure what reason I had for this back then (I remember thinking I had good reasons, but maybe I didn't) but I'm sorry I never got back to you on this. I would probably agree with you today.

Answer (score 4):

> That C/C++ will have an API callable from the higher-level
>   platform-dependent code.

If by this you mean that you intend this library to be a DLL which may be called from other languages, for example, .NET languages, then I strongly recommend having all public API as `extern "C"` functions that have only POD types as parameters and return values. That is, prefer `/*const*/ char*` over `std::string`. Remember, C++, unlike plain C, has no standard ABI.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a ten ton hammer to deal with strings in C/C++, then IBM's ICU project is for you.  http://site.icu-project.org/

ICU has all the tools for working with strings with really good unicode support.  It is an impressive and well-maintained open source product with a favorable license for commercial projects.

If you want to release your code as a .dll/.so for others to call, then you probably want to minimize your external dependencies.  You may want to stick to standard libraries or a more lightweight project in that case.

Comment: This is the most excellent link, thanks for that. And it's probably something that I will use.

Comment: @komrade-p Onward to ultimate victory!!

Answer (score 1):

A very common way to return a string to a caller is to accept a string buffer pointer and a character count of the buffer size. A useful convention is to return the number of characters copied into the buffer as the return value; this is especially valuable if you treat a buffer size of 0 as a special case and return the number of characters that are required (including the null terminator).

```
int GetString(char * buffer, int buffersize);
```

In C++ it is convenient to work with std::string instead, but this presents a problem: you can't rely on the implementation of std::string to be compatible between differently compiled parts of the program, i.e. between your main program and the library. By providing an inline function in a header file, you can ensure that the std::string is created in the same context as the caller and bypass this problem.

```
inline std::string GetString()
{
    std::string result(GetString(NULL, 0), 0);
    GetString(&result[0], result.size());
    result.erase(result.size() - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Dennis, it removes the terminating null which should *not* be part of the string. It's provided by Microsoft's implementation, but I can't find it at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ so it must be an enhancement. I'll fix the code.

Comment: No, it is part of the official interface, I just didn't understand why you were doing it.  That does make sense though.

Comment: Apparently, it is only part of the official interface in 0x.